# Android Eclipse: HTTP cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, http

Could someone explain why and how to fix this error message I am getting in Eclipse when programming or Android?

**HTTP cannot be resolved to a type**

Code example is below.

```
try {
                // Call class "HTTP" passing an URL using Async "execute"
                // Save returned string in "result"
                String result = new HTTP().execute("http://domain.com/file.php?ID=1&R=T").get();

                Log.i("EmonLog", "Result: "+result);

                result = result.replaceAll("\"","");
                TextView powerval = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information_message);
                powerval.setText("Result: " + result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("EmonLog", "Error: "+e);
            }
```

The program compiles and works perfectly, but I get this error and the red line under HTTP and I would like to understand why, and how to fix it.

Edit...Added some more information. This is the thread called by the execute.

```
    class HTTP extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            // Get the first parameter of the "params" which has been related to "String"
            String urlstring = params[0];
            // Log the string that contains the url
            Log.i("EmonLog", "HTTP Connecting: "+urlstring);
            // Convert the String into an actual URL
            URL url = new URL(urlstring);
            // Make the HTTP connection to the Internet
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Once the connection is done, try to store the information received into "reader"
            try {
                InputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                // Create a new String which will extract and contain the information received into the Buffered Input Stream
                String text = "";
                int i = 0;
                while((i=reader.read())!=-1)
                {
                    text += (char)i;
                }
                Log.i("EmonLog", "HTTP Response: "+text);
                result = text;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("EmonLog", "HTTP Exception: "+e);
            }
            finally {
                Log.i("EmonLog", "HTTP Disconnecting");
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("EmonLog", "HTTP Exception: "+e);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

my imports:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Show you're request code.

Comment: I dont understand. I am using this in two places. 1) inside a button press like this  bt_button_HVAC25Vmax.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      (2) and inside a thread like this   public void run() {

Comment: i run you're code and everything is working properly. Show you imports probably some problems with them.

Comment: and if you are using eclipse try to clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Yes, for me is also working correctly, but still get the error message eventhough it allows me to compile and run correctly. I have added my imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use HTTP as a name for an AsyncTask.

As you already have

```
org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP
```

as HTTP.

So please rename your AsyncTask to something else.

May be,

```
class HTTPTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

would be good enough.

Comment: But using the full package name should solve this issue, wouldn't it?

Comment: It might if OP uses properly, but is it good practice? @shyam

Comment: Great thanks, that seems to solve the error message. I have replaced it as you indicated and also in "String result = new HTTPTask().execute". Now I just have to analyze why this method is not the most appropiate way of doing the http request as Oleg informed me. Sorry I cant give positive feedback as I am new and dont have reputation yet.

Comment: @Serge that's ok. you can accept answer, so it gets removed from unanswered section, though. :) happy coding.

Comment: @MysticMagic Sure it's not a very bright idea. But sometimes it makes more sense to keep the more meaningful name (not necessarily the case here) doesn't it? Either way.. I was just saying. :)

Comment: @shyam can you explain what you mean by not a very bright idea? Just for learning purposes. Thanks

Comment: @Serge This would cause confusion if someone else was going through your code. (as in which `HTTP` is which?)